# user generic function to determine the instance type in swift

Tags: ios, generics

I have three classes that conforms to same object type (protocol).

```
    class Bicycle: Vehicle {}
    class Car : Vehicle {}
    class Truck: Vehicle {}
    class Bus : Vehicle {}
```

I have an array that holds objects of the above classes like

```
let vehicle1 = Car()
let vehicle2 = Bicycle()
let vehicle3 = Truck()
let vehicle4 = Car()
let vehicle5 = Bus()

let listOfVehicles = [vehicle1, vehicle2, vehicle3, vehicle4, vehicle5]
```

Now I need an array which will tell me the index of the parameter that passed.

```
func getFirstIndex<T: Vehicle>(for targetObject: T) -> Int {
     guard let index = listOfVehicles.firstIndex(where: {  $0 is targetObject.Type }) 
     else { 
        return -1
     }
     return index
}
```

If I call `getFirstIndex(for: vehicle3)`, I need to get 2 and

If I call `getFirstIndex(for: vehicle4)`, I need to get 0,
because vehicle4's type and vehicle1's type is same which is `Car`.

But I am getting compile-error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

Does anyone have any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `targetObject.Type` with `T`

Comment: Can you tell me why targetObject.Type don'ts work because saying targetObject.Type and T is essentially same.